# $( document ).on('turbolinks:load', function() { not working

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, turbolinks, ruby-on-rails-6

I'm trying to get my turbolinks document ready to work.  My code is very simple

```
$( document ).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
  console.log("It works on each visit!")
})
```

This is using rails 6.  That code is in the middle of my application.js file:

```
// This file is automatically compiled by Webpack, along with any other files
// present in this directory. You're encouraged to place your actual application logic in
// a relevant structure within app/javascript and only use these pack files to reference
// that code so it'll be compiled.
// Loads all Semantic javascripts
//= require jquery
//= require semantic-ui
//= require rails-ujs
//= require activestorage
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
// Uncomment to copy all static images under ../images to the output folder and reference
// them with the image_pack_tag helper in views (e.g <%= image_pack_tag 'rails.png' %>)
// or the `imagePath` JavaScript helper below.
//
// const images = require.context('../images', true)
// const imagePath = (name) => images(name, true)

$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
$('.message .close')
  .on('click', function() {
    $(this).closest('.message').transition('fade');
  })
;
})

$( document ).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
  console.log("It works on each visit!")
})
```

I have both jquery and turbolinks gems in my gemfile and bundle has been installed.  Currently no console log is displayed, but there are no error messages either.

Comment: rails-ujs and turbolinks should be loaded before jquery.  use `document.addEventListener`, hope it will work -

document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", () => {
  console.log("loaded")
});

Comment: @SalmanMahmud why would that make any difference at all?

Comment: @max i didn't notice that require_self is missing here.

Comment: ’jQuery.on’ is just a pimped up version of addEventListener anyways. So there is no reason the later would work if the former doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you don't have a `require_self` directive in your mainfest.

```
// This file is automatically compiled by Webpack, along with any other files
// present in this directory. You're encouraged to place your actual application logic in
// a relevant structure within app/javascript and only use these pack files to reference
// that code so it'll be compiled.
// Loads all Semantic javascripts
//= require jquery
//= require semantic-ui
//= require rails-ujs
//= require activestorage
//= require turbolinks
//= require_self
//= require_tree .
```

The reason its a separate directive is that it lets you affect the order your files are compiled.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response.  I added the require_self right where you told me to.  The console log is still not firing in my browser console!

Comment: Hmm it might not work the same way after sprockets was replaced by webpacker. Try placing it in another file in the same directory instead.

Comment: by "it" do you mean the lines of code with the turbolinks?  Or that require_self?